# Can I use Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies to convert word,excel to PDF

Tags: .net, pdf, pdf-generation, ms-office, office-pia

Can I use Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies to convert word, excel to PDF? How easy is it? Any C# example?

Comment: did you tried this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305.aspx ?

Comment: Microsoft frowns on such use as they are not scalable. For simple conversions, yes they are great but not for production.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the interop assemblies without having office installed as well. Once office is installed it works, but to make it reliable and scalable a lot of work is required, but it is not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Document.SaveAs to save as a PDF.

It is un-supported and tricky to do this in a non-interactive (or server side) manner.