# Making a pdf copy of a csv file programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, csv

I have a csv file and I need to make a pdf copy in the console application that creates the csv. All I have found 3rd party libraries for working with pdf but I don't want to use that. Can I just make a copy and save it as a pdf? If so, how?

Also, I'm using C#, in case you didn't read the title.

Comment: Hi Jason and welcome to the wiki. Try this "[C#] PDF" in the search section of stack-overflow (will show you QA of PDF phrase in C# tag). There are many results that may help you pal.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link hope it will help you.

```
http://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=72954
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the csv with excel.
than use office PIA (interop) to save as PDF.
see:

[Can I use Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies to convert word,excel to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942627/can-i-use-microsoft-office-2010-primary-interop-assemblies-to-convert-word-exce)

Answer (score -1):

first read the csv files using c# code, and load that data's into DataTable,

write the datatable values into pdf file using c#

may this idea will help 4 u